# how to redirect from axios in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am trying to redirect in react native am new to reactnative can anyone help me with this

```
 axios.post('http://10.0.2.2:8000/client/user', Data)

      .then(() => {
        //if succcess redirect to another url and pass data to that url
      })

      .catch(error => {
        alert(error);
      });
  }
```

i want  to another to a **url** and pass data to that url when **.then** is executed

is this the correct method to pass this

```
<PaperProvider>
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen
              options={{headerShown: false}}
              name="Home"
              component={HomeScreen}
            />
           
            <Stack.Screen name="Home_scrren" component={Home_scrren} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Pregnant" component={Pregnant} />
          
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
      </PaperProvider>
```

Comment: @aplha i have updated question stcak i am using

Comment: So after the api call you want to navigate to a another screen and wants to call another api right ?

Comment: if the .then is exexuted i want to naviagte to another screen and pass the data to that screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can navigate if `API` is successful

```
axios
  .post("http://10.0.2.2:8000/client/user", Data)

  .then((res) => {
    //if succcess redirect to another url and pass data to that url
    if (res.status == 200) {
      props.navigation.navigate("Pregnant", { data: res.data });
    } else {
      // show alert or your logic
    }
  })

  .catch((error) => {
    alert(error);
  });
```

And this is how you can get data from the another screen:
[Read more on this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/)

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log("route.params ==>", props.route.params);
}, []);
```

Comment: @apha property route doesnot exist error i am geting in usefffct

Comment: sorry it should be props.route.params. I'll update the code

Comment: now log is coming like this  `route.params ==> {"data": undefined}`

Comment: when your navigating try this  props.navigation.navigate("Pregnant", { data: res.data });